# Servlet Filter for all requests

Tags: java, servlets, servlet-filters

I am wondering, how can I set in the web.xml a Filter that is called on every request?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

just create a filter, and map it to /*

e.g.

```
    <filter>
        <filter-name>MyFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.mycompany.MyFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>MyFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

Comment: The filter isnt being called on for example http://mysite.com?blahblah, when the query string is tied not to a servlet but to the root url. Do you know of a solution?

Comment: it should get called. can you please check on how your servlet associated with mysite.com is mapped? if mysite.com is a static page rendered directly off the web server, may be the java app never gets a hit for that url.

Comment: if so, then how could I tie a filter to the root url?

Comment: if the root url is not served via the java app, you can not attach the filter unfortunately :-). if you need the filter to be served, you can either mimic the behaviour on webserver using redirect rules, or get the root url served by the java app as well.

Answer (score 1):

Add a filter mapping with '*'  wildcard.

```
  <filter-mapping>
   <filter-name>TestFilter</filter-name>
   <url-pattern>*</url-pattern>
 </filter-mapping>
```

Comment: The filter isnt being called on for example http://mysite.com?blahblah, when the query string is tied not to a servlet but to the root url. Do you know of a solution?

Comment: I have an exact same problem, my filter is not called for every requests from the client. I need a filter to catch all requests no-matter if they are on application level or jboss container level...

Comment: Can we catch all the requests(webapp & non-webapp contextx) in Tomcat through the servlet filter?

Comment: @M.S.Naidu Have you found the solution for it? I know that it is an old thread but I am facing the same issue. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

*Spring Security Web* defines all urls as `/**`. So it should work for all requests.

See-
`org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher`

It defines `MATCH_ALL` constant as `/**` and this final variable is used in `matches` method.

Pasting below the method definition from `org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher` where it decides if some request url matches or not. If the pattern is set to `MATCH_ALL` aka `/**` it returns `true`.

```
public boolean matches(HttpServletRequest request) {
        if (this.httpMethod != null && StringUtils.hasText(request.getMethod())
                && this.httpMethod != valueOf(request.getMethod())) {
            if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
                logger.debug("Request '" + request.getMethod() + " "
                        + getRequestPath(request) + "'" + " doesn't match '"
                        + this.httpMethod + " " + this.pattern + "'");
            }

            return false;
        }

        if (this.pattern.equals(MATCH_ALL)) {
            if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
                logger.debug("Request '" + getRequestPath(request)
                        + "' matched by universal pattern '/**'");
            }

            return true;
        }

        String url = getRequestPath(request);

        if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
            logger.debug("Checking match of request : '" + url + "'; against '"
                    + this.pattern + "'");
        }

        return this.matcher.matches(url);
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

Are you sure the request is hitting the controller/servlet? If it's making an Ajax call or running some JS then the filter won't hit.